# Azure cli to run Query Pack query

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-log-analytics, azure-cli2

I can connect to log-analytics using azure cli ok but when listing the saved queries:

```
az monitor log-analytics workspace saved-search list
```

the Query Pack query I created doesn't show. The Query Pack query works in the Azure Portal when I load it.

Is there a way to run a query in log analytics that is from a Query Pack using azure cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now,  this feature to run query pack query using **Azure cli** is not available. You can do the same using the **Azure portal**.

You can refer to [Log Analytics Query packs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/log-analytics-query-packs/ba-p/2314721),   [Query packs in Azure Monitor Logs (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/query-packs) and submit your feedback at [Azure Monitor-Log Analytics](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics)